# Javascript or JQuery Password Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords, prompt

I've found similar questions on the net, but not a viable solution to them.

My question, as the title suggests, is how could I leverage jQuery or Javascript to create a **password prompt** when, for example, a button is clicked.

So the following, but instead of showing the text, I'd like the text field act as a password field.

```
var pass1 = 'hello123';
password=prompt('Please enter password to view page')    
if (password==pass1)
   alert('password correct! Press ok to continue.')
```

I want something similar to the following image.!

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly useful to ask somebody for a password that they can *see* in your code...  But if you really want to, then you can use something like a jQuery modal dialog.  All you're doing is overlaying a `div` on the page with some form elements and handling the button clicks within that form.  All of which is basic jQuery functionality.

Comment: That window is not JS, it's HTTP Basic Auth

Comment: @David yes. This was for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @zerkms could this be done in either jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Exactly the same - nope.

Comment: The problem with doing password authentication at the front end level is that end user can circumvent the whole process by just disabling javascript on their browsers. That is why we need back-end code to verify a validated request from the client side at the server side level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you could do (like @David mentioned) is use a model window or a child window to spawn off a form to fill out.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="prompt" value="Click for authentication prompt"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var theButton = document.getElementById("prompt");

theButton.onclick = function () {
    var thePrompt = window.open("", "", "widht=500");
    var theHTML = "";

    theHTML += "<p>The server http://localhost:8888 requires a username and password. The server says: These are restricted files, please authenticate yourself.</p>";
    theHTML += "<br/>";
    theHTML += "Username: <input type='text' id='theUser' placeholder='Enter Username...'/>";
    theHTML += "<br />";
    theHTML += "Password: <input type='text' id='thePass' placeholder='Enter Password...'/>";
    theHTML += "<br />";
    theHTML += "<input type='button' value='OK' id='authOK'/>";
    thePrompt.document.body.innerHTML = theHTML;

    var theUser = thePrompt.document.getElementById("theUser").value;
    var thePass = thePrompt.document.getElementById("thePass").value;
    thePrompt.document.getElementById("authOK").onclick = function () {
        doAuthentication(theUser, thePass);
    }
}

function doAuthentication(user, pass) {
    //do authentication
}
```

Obviously, if you're going after the same look and feel of the window you're working with, you'll want to apply some CSS and JavaScript to make it more 'pretty' so that it mirrors what you're going for.