# How to hide my password in html webpage?

Tags: html

I am very new to HTML programming. I have created a webpage which will ask for password and then proceed to the next webpage, but my password is visible when i enter it in the webpage. how can i change it into bullets or * ?

This is the HTML code :

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="logo page.jpg" alt="TCIL" width="1590" height="470">
<p><font color="blue"><font size="5"><center>Corporate Social Responsibility</center></font></p>
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
while (testV < 3) {
if (!pass1) 
history.go(-1);
if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {
alert('password accepted');
window.open('E:/MyCSRAPP/expense statement/400140.htm');
break;
} 
testV+=1;
var pass1 = 
prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
history.go(-1);
return " ";
} 
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Login to continue" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out if any option is there

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403655/javascript-or-jquery-password-prompt

Answer (score 0):

The popup is browser controlled and you won't be able able to modify it.

You can use a input type element and it will do the job:

```
 <input type="password" size="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't hide your password in HTML.

If it has been over the wire into client's browser, you can't hide anything there.

You need to do password checking on a server, not in client's browser.